# D3 Parse and Display JSON (from Python Dataframe)

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am looking to create a stock chart. I have been trying to use the example from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955 but I'm having trouble parsing the format of the json file that my python dataframe outputs:

Here is an example of the json:

```
var dataset = [{"1412121600000":{"Long":100.0,"Short":100.0,"Combined":100.0},
                "1412208000000":{"Long":100.7259540416,"Short":99.9845645596,"Combined":100.7105186013},
                "1412294400000":{"Long":100.4436402904,"Short":98.8837985253,"Combined":99.3194897889},
                "1412553600000":{"Long":100.4436402904,"Short":98.9995341224,"Combined":99.4357353278},
                "1412640000000":{"Long":99.5664445414,"Short":100.5277244418,"Combined":100.1022654968},
                "1412726400000":{"Long":101.6333965937,"Short":98.7695530192,"Combined":100.4296105442},
                "1412812800000":{"Long":101.8552090464,"Short":100.7284660335,"Combined":102.6406329748},
                "1412899200000":{"Long":101.5628181559,"Short":101.8782213959,"Combined":103.5175690128},
                "1413158400000":{"Long":100.6352059402,"Short":103.5518262499,"Combined":104.27263855},
                "1413244800000":{"Long":99.5664445414,"Short":103.3915337819,"Combined":103.0038388108},
                "1413331200000":{"Long":98.3464414352,"Short":104.0910952724,"Combined":102.4386550712}}];
```

I need to format the key of the dictionary as the date and access the node with the data but not sure how to. I've been trying variations from the example but it doesn't seem to work:

```
d3.json(dataset, function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        ??
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend is to begin with reformatting a little. You should make each point look something like this:

```
{"date":"1412121600000","values":["Long":100.0,"Short":100.0,"Combined" :100.0]}
```

Then you can reference them with .date or .value. For example if "date" is supposed to be a value on the x axis you can go

```
.attr('x',function(d){return d.date;})
```

with some Date.parse() function.

Notice for example how Mike does it

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  });

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;
```

Here he has "date" as a column and can reference it as such. With JSON that is done as I showed you.